# Unsupported scheme (protocol) - uGet error

Tags: uget

I am trying to download a `PDF` file using uGet. The download is interrupted and Uget gives me the following error:

```
Message: Unsupported scheme (protocol)
```

Also, uGet does not capture the file name or extension correctly (see below figure). The download keeps failing even when I try to change the file name/extension in the download dialogue. The problem also occurred with other files (e.g., *.NC).

Incorrect file name and extension

[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

"blob" is not a protocol. It is a pseudo protocol and not one that is supported by uget. Please alter the URL to a valid one to download files (like http, https, ftp)

If you know the website, open it, press F12, Network and you can search for your file. The corresponding source code will show an actual URL to the file you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the provided steps did not work.
Also, the same problem remains, even when I try to download a simple pdf file from for example google drive.
Why the original download manager in my browser able to download the file correctly and uGet cannot?